# Craft 3 language switcher

Tags: localization, craft3, multi-site

Does anybody successfully implemented a language switch run Craft 3? Trying the Craft 2 variant slightly adjusted but still running into issues: Invalid site handle: nl

```
<ul>
{% set otherLocales = craft.app.i18n.siteLocaleIds|without(craft.locale) %}
{% for locale in otherLocales %}
   {% set localeEntry = craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale(locale).one() %}
    {#  set localeCategory = craft.categories.group('worksCat').locale(locale).first #}
    {% if localeEntry.locale is defined and localeEntry.locale == locale %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ localeEntry.getUrl() }}">
            <img src="/{{ craft.app.i18n.getLocaleById(locale) }}.svg"  {{ craft.app.i18n.getLocaleById(locale).nativeName }}
        </a>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ localeCategory.getUrl() }}">
            <img src="/{{ craft.app.i18n.getLocaleById(locale) }}.svg" > {{ craft.app.i18n.getLocaleById(locale).nativeName }}
        </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The concept of localization has changed in Craft 3, there are not only `locales` anymore - now you have different sites and site groups.

**Example without multisite - only different locals**

You can get all available sites for an entry with

```
{% set supportedSites = entry.getSupportedSites %}
```

This will return you an array of all supported sites for the entry.

```
{% for siteForEntry in entry.getSupportedSites %}
    {# get the site #}
    {% set site = craft.app.getSites.getSiteById(siteForEntry.siteId) %}
    {# check if it's the current site #}
    {% if site.id == entry.siteId %}
        active site = {{ site.id }} {{ site.language }} 
    {% else %}
        {# if it's not the current site, get the entry for this site #}
        {% set entryForOtherSite = craft.entries.id(entry.id).site(site).one() %}
        link to site with id {{ entryForOtherSite.siteId }} <a href="{{ entryForOtherSite.getUrl() }}">{{ site.language }} - {{ entryForOtherSite.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

When you take a look at your `/admin/utilities/deprecation-errors` you'll see many records because all your `locale` functions will do this

```
public function locale(string $value)
{
    Craft::$app->getDeprecator()->log('ElementQuery::locale()', 'The “locale” element query param has been deprecated. Use “site” or “siteId” instead.');
    $this->site($value);

    return $this;
}
```

They tell you: "This function is deprecated, use "site" instead"

**Example with multisite - different sites and locales**

If you are going to have multiple different sites with multiple locales you can manage each site in one group and insert all the locales for these sites in each group.

```
- Site group A
    - language A (siteId 1)
    - Language B (siteId 2)
- Site group B
    - Language A (siteId 3)
    - Language C (siteId 4)
```

For Example if the user is in site group A you want to show only language A and language B but not Language C even if the entry exists in all sites.
So you can grab the group of the current site and loop through all sites of the group.

```
{% set currentSite = craft.app.sites.currentSite %}
{% for siteInGroup in currentSite.getGroup.getSites() %}
    {% if siteInGroup.id == entry.siteId %}
        active site = {{ siteInGroup.id }}{{ siteInGroup.language }}
    {% else %}
        {% set entryForOtherSite = craft.entries.id(entry.id).site(siteInGroup).one() %}
        link to site {{ entryForOtherSite.siteId }} <a href="{{ entryForOtherSite.getUrl() }}">{{ siteInGroup.language }} - {{ entryForOtherSite.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I really like this answer, however often you don't have an entry available in the templates. So you should check for entry, category and maybe fallback to the homepage?

Comment: It's great that you have to come to StackExchange to figure out how to use a core feature.

Answer (score 5):

Little addition with a fallback to the homepage and check if entry exist.
currentSite is a global variable already defined in craft3 https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/templating/global-variables.html#currentsite

```
<ul>
  {% for site in currentSite.group.sites %}
    <li class="{% if currentSite.id == site.id %} is-active{% endif %}">
      {% set url = alias(site.baseUrl) %}
      {% if entry is defined %}
        {% set entryForOtherSite = craft.entries.id(entry.id).site(site).one() %}
        {% if entryForOtherSite %}
          {% set url = entryForOtherSite.getUrl() %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
      <a href="{{ url }}">{{ site.name }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

As of today, **Site Switcher** is now available in the plugin store! *

It was called "Language Link" in Craft 2, but the premise is the same... It allows you to switch between sites while staying on the same page.

```html
{% set element = (category ?? entry ?? null) %}

<ul>
    <li><a href="{{ siteSwitcher('english', element) }}">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ siteSwitcher('spanish', element) }}">Español</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ siteSwitcher('french', element) }}">Français</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ siteSwitcher('german', element) }}">Deutsch</a></li>
</ul>
```

> https://github.com/doublesecretagency/craft-siteswitcher

** Disclaimer: I am the author of Site Switcher.*

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [SEOmatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic) for Craft CMS 3, there's a built-in function that will make it super easy to do:

**`seomatic.helper.getLocalizedUrls(URI, SITE_ID)`** - Return a list of localized URLs for a given `URI` that are in the `SITE_ID` site's group. Both `URI` and `SITE_ID` are optional, and will use the current request's `URI` and the current site's `SITE_ID` if omitted.

c.f.: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic#helper-functions-seomatichelper

Comment: Any chance any of you knows how to output the language's name instead of code?  English instead of EN, like we could do with locale.nativeName.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my language switcher for Craft CMS 3:

http://craftsnippets.com/articles/universal-language-switcher-for-craft-cms?s=s

It works for Entries, categories and other elements with their own URLs and has an option for an automatic appending country flag to language links.