# Can you get the baseUrl for site by handle or id?

Tags: multi-site

I am making a super simple language switcher. And I was wondering if there is a way to get the baseUrl for a site by id or handle, something like this:

```
<a class="navbar-item" href="{{baseUrl.german}}"><img class="circular-square" src="/images/global/german.png" alt="Germany Flag" />DE<span class="sr-only">Deutsch</span></a>
```

What I'm trying to avoid doing is:

```
<a class="navbar-item" href="/de"><img class="circular-square" src="/images/global/german.png" alt="Germany Flag" />DE<span class="sr-only">Deutsch</span></a>
```

Or is that just how to you do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{% set site = craft.app.getSites().getSiteById(1) %}
{% set site = craft.app.getSites().getSiteByHandle('handle') %}
{{ site.baseUrl }}
```

But I would rather suggest you to grab the entries URL for a certain site in your language switcher

```
{% set entryInOtherSite = craft.entries.id(entry.id).siteId(2).one() %}
{{ entry.getUrl() }}
```

I'm not sure why you even ask this question since everything is well documented [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23710/craft-3-language-switcher) since you "answered" that question

Comment: What I was trying to do here is different than my previous post. Thanks for the help.