# Does entry ID change with locale?

Tags: entries, localization, id

I have a condition that checks entry Id. The condition seems to not work for Japanese locale but works fine on English. I would think that entry ID remains the same irrespective of the locale. Please confirm or correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: The ID won't change in different locales, check this answer for reference : https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23710/craft-3-language-switcher 

You could also test it in your templates e.g. 
`{{ craft.entries.siteId(1).one().title }}`
`{{ craft.entries.siteId(0).one().title }}`

Comment: Sounds like a perfect valid answer to me @HendrikEng if you want to add it. :)

Answer (score 3):

The ID won't change in different locales, check this answer for reference: [Craft 3 language switcher](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23710/craft-3-language-switcher)

You could also test it in your templates e.g. :

```
{% for locale in craft.app.sites.getAllSites() %}
    {{ craft.entries.siteId(locale.id).one().id }} : {{ craft.entries.siteId(locale.id).one().title }}
{% endfor %}
```